# Spinner with file names and count

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to edit this code to show a spinner, the file name and total files moved updated for every hundred files moved. I have the spinner part worked out but I'm stuck getting the filenames and an accurate count. In this case I have 3,554 files but it stops at 3,500. I want to integrate it into another set of code that actually does the moving of the files. That code from Magoo is listed at the end of the post. Any help very much appreciated.

**Spinner Code**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\temp\xmls"
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
SET "filesmoved=0"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
For %%A in (*.xml) do set /a cnt+=1
Echo %cnt% files.
For /L %%I in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    set /a filesmoved += 1, hundred = filesmoved %% 100
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !hundred! equ 0 call :spinner
    endlocal
)

goto :EOF

:spinner
set "moved=%filesmoved%"
:spinner2
if %filesmoved% geq 400 set /a filesmoved -= 400 & goto :spinner2
set /a spinpos = filesmoved / 100
for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do set /P "=%BS%"<NUL
set /P "=Moving XML Files !spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!   %moved% Files moved"<NUL
goto :EOF
```

**Batch move XML Files**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*_*.xml" '
 ) DO SET "filename=%%a"&CALL :process

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6delims=_" %%m IN ("%filename%") DO SET "date1=%%m"&SET "date2=%%n"&SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 GOTO :eof
ECHO(MD .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%
ECHO(MOVE "%filename%" .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%\
GOTO :EOF
```

**Latest Code**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
Title Reorganizing XMLs - DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW!
mode con: cols=100 lines=6
set "sourcedir=C:\Temp\XMLs"
pushd %sourcedir%
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set "spaces=          "
SET /a filesMoved = 0, spinPos = 0, prev = 0

echo Moving XML Files...

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,7) do set "BS=!BS!!BS!"
for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do set "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

For %%A in (*.xml) do set /a cnt+=1
echo.
Echo %cnt% files.
echo.

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xml" ' ) DO (
        set /a filesmoved += 1 
        call :spinner !filesmoved! "%%~nxa"
)
call :spinner %filesMoved% Done.
endlocal & echo;
exit /b 0

:spinner <filecount> <filename>
set /a spinPos += 1, spinPos %%= 4, ten = %~1 / 10 * 10
if "%~2"=="Done." set ten=%~1
set "str=[!spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!] %ten% files moved... [%~2]"
set "str=%str:~0,79%"
call :length len "%str%"
set /a diff = 79 - len
if %diff% gtr 0 set "str=%str%!spaces:~-%diff%!"
set /P "=!BS:~-79!%str%"<NUL
if "%~2" NEQ "Done." call :process %~2
exit /b 0

:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~2"=="" (set ret=0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~2"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
                set /a ret += %%I
                set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
        )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
exit /b 0

:process
FOR /f "tokens=2,3,6delims=_" %%m IN ("%~1") DO SET "date1=%%m"&SET "date2=%%n"&SET "whichdate=%%o"
IF DEFINED whichdate SET "date1=%date2%"
IF NOT DEFINED date2 exit /b 1
If not exist .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2% MD .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%
MOVE %~1 .\%date1:~0,4%\%date1:~4,2%\
```

Comment: @Rojo Any other thoughts on this? Here is the latest code I have come up with.

Comment: So you want the file name and count displayed only for every 100th file, but the spinner to rotate a notch with every file?

Comment: I want the filenames displayed for each file and the spinner to continously rotate for each file but I only want the file count to go up for every 100th file. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do all of this work? Just use robocopy.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I didn't know Robocopy could do everything I want this script to do. Can you add an answer that shows how it can?

Comment: You can find out for yourself what robocopy can do by doing a [quick search for it](http://bing.com/?q=robocopy). It supports directory replication/mirroring, logging, automatic retry, bandwidth throttling, and much more.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm quite familiar with Robocopy and I have used it extensively. Like I said, I'm not familiar with how Robocopy can extract the date from a file and create a folder tree based on it. Nor am I familiar with how it can list the files that are being moved with a spinner to show activity and finally, I'm on XP with no way to get or use Robocopy until my employer finally stops having meetings and just gets us upgraded to win 7, so the point is moot. :)

Comment: Best wishes on that endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a promise is a promise I guess.  :)

OK.  Part of the difficulty you'll encounter, whether you realize it or not, is that capturing a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to a variable and `set /P`ing it to the console merely moves the cursor back one column.  It doesn't replace the characters with blank spaces.  So if you're going to be echoing out filenames, backspacing then `set /P "=filename.ext"` will leave some unpleasantness displayed if `filename.ext` is shorter than a previous `filename.ext`.

You could `set /P "= %BS%%BS%" to overwrite each character with a space, but doing this with a`for /L` loop will cause the line to flicker, also unpleasantly.

So my solution is to capture 128 backspaces to a variable, then use numeric substring extraction to `set /P "=%BS:~-num%"` to eliminate the flickering.  I also space fill then re-backspace at the end of the line if the current line is shorter than the previous line.  And finally, I limit the length of the line to 80 characters to avoid line wrapping (from which no amount of programmatic backspacing can recover).

For my testing, I just used the contents of my `C:` drive for the list of files to loop through.  If you need help integrating Magoo's `:process` code, leave a comment and I'll help you out when I get a chance.  I've gotta jet for tonight, though.  For now, save this and run it as a proof of concept.  It's only a laser light show.  It doesn't actually move anything in its current state.

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "spinChars=\|/-"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set "spaces=          "
SET /a filesMoved = 0, spinPos = 0, prev = 0

echo Moving XML Files...

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,7) do set "BS=!BS!!BS!"
for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do set "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

for /R "C:\" %%I in (*) do (
    set /a filesMoved += 1
    call :spinner !filesMoved! "%%~nxI"
)

call :spinner %filesMoved% Done.
endlocal & echo;

goto :EOF

:spinner <filecount> <filename>
set /a spinPos += 1, spinPos %%= 4, hundred = %~1 / 100 * 100
if "%~2"=="Done." set hundred=%~1
set "str=[!spinChars:~%spinPos%,1!] %hundred% files moved... (%~2)"
set "str=%str:~0,79%"
call :length len "%str%"
set /a diff = 79 - len
if %diff% gtr 0 set "str=%str%!spaces:~-%diff%!"
set /P "=!BS:~-79!%str%"<NUL
goto :EOF

:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~2"=="" (set ret=0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~2"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
        set /a ret += %%I
        set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help rojo. I figured out the rest and updated my latest code with the changes. If you see any way I can improve upon it, please let me know. I changed it from every 100 files to every 10 as it was taking a bit to long to update.